# discord.py: ideas on how to speed up the processing time of this command

Tags: performance, optimization, discord.py

I have a command that finds the oldest and newest users in a server. It checks through every user, until it find all the nessesary information. It works fine until I use it in a server with 2000 users takes like 10 seconds to process and I can't use any other command with the bot furring that time.
Code of the command:

```
    @commands.command()
    async def oldest(self, ctx, page: int=1):
        await oldest_newest(self, ctx, page, "Oldest")
    # tnewest
    @commands.command()
    async def newest(self, ctx, page: int=1):
        await oldest_newest(self, ctx, page, "Newest")

async def oldest_newest(self, ctx, page, sort_type):
    page = abs(int(page))
    if page > 99: page = 99

    x1 = x2 = x3 = x4 = x5 = x6 = x7 = x8 = x9 = x10 = None
    searchint = (page-1)*10
    for x in ctx.guild.members:
        if sort_type == "Oldest": creation_pos = sum(m.created_at < x.created_at for m in ctx.guild.members if m.created_at is not None) + 1
        if sort_type == "Newest": creation_pos = sum(m.created_at > x.created_at for m in ctx.guild.members if m.created_at is not None) + 1
        if creation_pos == searchint+1: x1 = x
        if creation_pos == searchint+2: x2 = x
        if creation_pos == searchint+3: x3 = x
        if creation_pos == searchint+4: x4 = x
        if creation_pos == searchint+5: x5 = x
        if creation_pos == searchint+6: x6 = x
        if creation_pos == searchint+7: x7 = x
        if creation_pos == searchint+8: x8 = x
        if creation_pos == searchint+9: x9 = x
        if creation_pos == searchint+10: x10 = x 
    
    members_sorted =[]
    if x1 is not None: members_sorted.append(x1)
    if x2 is not None: members_sorted.append(x2)
    if x3 is not None: members_sorted.append(x3)
    if x4 is not None: members_sorted.append(x4)
    if x5 is not None: members_sorted.append(x5)
    if x6 is not None: members_sorted.append(x6)
    if x7 is not None: members_sorted.append(x7)
    if x8 is not None: members_sorted.append(x8)
    if x9 is not None: members_sorted.append(x9)
    if x10 is not None: members_sorted.append(x10)

    cycle_int = 0
    output_string = ""
    for x in members_sorted:
        cycle_int = cycle_int + 1
        output_string += f"**{cycle_int+((page-1)*10)}** - {x} - {x.created_at.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')}\n"

    em = discord.Embed(color=self.client.Blue)
    em.add_field(name=f"{sort_type} accounts in **{ctx.guild.name}**", value=output_string, inline=False)

    em.set_footer(text=f"Page: {page}")
    em.timestamp = datetime.utcnow()
        
    await ctx.send(embed=em)
```

I'm fairly new to discord bots and learnt everything off YouTube or here. Though this is the first time I'm actually asking for help. Any ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure if it is faster as I can't test it myself on a big server, but you could try to get every member along with their created_at date, append it to a list and then sort the list by the created_at date.

Very simplified example:

```
    @commands.command()
    async def oldestmember(self, ctx):
        everyuser = []
        for member in ctx.guild.members:
            userinfo = (member.name, member.created_at)
            everyuser.append(userinfo)
    
        everyuser.sort(key=lambda x:x[1])

        print(everyuser)
```

And then if you wanted to get the newest member you would reverse the list with `everyuser.reverse()`.

Hope this helps at least a little bit

Comment: Thnx this made it much faster like it's instant now. although the `everyuser.reverse()` didn't work for me. This is what it ended up looking like if you are interested: https://pastebin.com/hS605Yur